# Maintaining PowerPoint in full screen while cliking in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

I am working on an application that consists of a `JFrame` that runs on top of Microsoft PowerPoint. It is an invisible frame so that you can see what PowerPoint is showing. This frame has certain buttons that I want to be able to click, while a PowerPoint presentation is on "PowerPoint presentation mode" (full screen).

The problem is that, when I click a button in the frame, PowerPoint minimizes. I want PowerPoint to be kept in full screen while I click the buttons. This is the code I used to set the frame to be in front of PowerPoint.

```
jframe.setUndecorated(true);
jframe.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
jframe.setVisible(true);    
jframe.setResizable(false);  
jframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Some of the solutions I considered were:

1. Tried using `jframe.setFocusable(false);` so that the focus is maintained in PowerPoint app, instead of changing to my app. I also used that method in the `JPanel` and the buttons that are in the frame. But it doesn't seem to do the job.
2. This second solution works, however it is a bad one. When pressing one of the buttons, it minimizes PowerPoint, afterwards I use java `Robot` class to press cmd+tab (or alt+tab in windows) and since the last app that had the focus was PowerPoint, it comes back into full screen and my app is still on top. The problem is that the user will notice that, and there should be an easier way around this.

Comment: "Full Screen Exclusive Mode" is just that, exclusive, it's designed to only allow a single window to have complete a full control over the screen, without interference from any other windows

Comment: Isn´t there a way to maintain the focus on PowerPoint while still receiving the click events in the buttons? @MadProgrammer

Comment: If Powerpoint is running in "FSEM" no.  It thinks that it is the only active window in the system.  This is done for a number of reasons, one of which is performance